# authenticate via .htaccess on custom login

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

So my problem is this - i have custom authenticate code that writes in db `online` table ip, session id and user id(if login and password match) based on registered user data. 
Soo i have some js scripts that are only needed when you are authenticated and i dont want them to be accessible if you are not logged in(its not unsecured but why to give playground), and i want all the script to be in one .js file. 
Soo i thoght maybe i can make that folder with .htacces password protection and when i log into admin panel some php code make me also logged in in that appache system - is this possible? or i need to make js file php and then include it or something else? im baffled.

Comment: that's an interesting concept (sending different JS content based on user's logged in status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can do that!  But there is a much simpler way. Just use a php file as your script tag's `src` attribute, and setup that file to handle the request:

```
<script src="/path/to/js_handler.php"></script>
```

The PHP file controls which Javascript is sent to the client. This is because PHP script can tell whether the user is logged in by looking at `$_SESSION` variables:

**js_handler.php**

```
<?php
    if(session_status()=== PHP_SESSION_NONE) session_start();
    $loggedIn = false;

    //determine whether the user is logged in by looking at values set
    // in $_SESSION by the login script. This is just an example
    if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['expires'] > time()) 
        $loggedIn = true;

    //set JS header (otherwise the browser will expect an HTML file)
    header('Content-Type: application/javascript');

    //now send the right file to the browser
    if($loggedIn){
        //instruct the browser and proxies to never cache this file. Probably
        //better just set short caching (1-2hrs) to reduce server load
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        header("Expires: 0");

        readfile('/path/to/private.js');
    }
    else{
        //allow caching and reusing for up to 7 days
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=" . 60*60*24*7); //max age allowed: 7 days
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 60*60*24*7).' GMT');

        readfile('/path/to/public.js');
    }
```

Comment: thank you for sugestion and it worked like a charm, but one more question - does browser chache javascript that is included in this maner?

Comment: `.php` files are typically not cached but JavaScript files are cached so I don't know what would happen by default. However, you can control it yourself by setting cache headers. I edited my answer to show you how to tell the browser to cache for 7 days (for `public.js`) and how to tell the browser to never cache (for `private.js`). Realize that if you set `never cache` the browser will keep redownloading every time it opens a new page that uses the script. That will slow your site down and might bother your users. Maybe a short cache (1-6hrs) is better